# How to create directory in specified path?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to create directory. This is the code:

```
from os import mkdir

mkdir(*name of new directory*)
```

When run from terminal, this creates directory in the folder that contains this python script. How to specify a path where I want to create new directory but remaining the possibility to name it?

Comment: Specify the absolute path of the directory you want to create.

Comment: How to do that? @GWW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mkdir(*absolute path of new directory*)
```

So, for example:

```
mkdir("c:/users/me/desktop/new_dir")  # for Windows
mkdir("/home/users/me/Desktop/new_dir") # for Linux
```

Comment: But where I add name of new directory? @Robᵩ

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić In my example, the name of the new directory is "new_dir", and it is to be created in "c:/users/me/desktop".

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
os.makedirs('/your/path/new_dir')
# Creating a new directory under current directory
path = os.getcwd()+'/new_dir'
os.makedirs(path)
```